# error of reading data in socket programming

Tags: c#

i wrote a console application. i used socket programming . 
i get  error in below cod. transfer speed of data is 10ms . after a period of time i get a error on " while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)" line .

```
while (true)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    String data = null;
    int i;
    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
       ...
    }
```

error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   System.dll     Additional information: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection:  A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a   period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to 
>   respond.

Comment: Don't you need to wait when the server responds you with an event or something like it? I think, you problem is that you are trying to read an empty stream.

Comment: i get data from clinet on every 10 ms. what event i can use?

Answer (score 0):

When you do IO stuff or network stuff, your code needs to be able to handle excpetional circumstances, so say with a socket, the server suddenly shuts down their end of a connection, your code needs to be able to handle that.  And your code isn't doing anything with that exception.

To do this you need to put your code in a try/catch block

```
try
{
    // put socket code stuff here
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    // put excpetion code here.
}
```

Hope this helps.